Pivot the query result to date
I have the following data (https://i.sstatic.net/6HWG4GTB.png)
And i want to plot the data in the following format
(https://i.sstatic.net/f0wYvf6t.png)
what will the be big query
I am expecting the data to be transposed alike what we do in pivot table
Who i am get the date into column and take the gb usage data under the date and show the datavise usage against each customer
